# SQL Syntax - query issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query which is supposed to create a temptable using the join function between two tables found within the same database & server. The query runs without syntax error but the issue is that the results are blank. I am still learning sql so I am having a hard time figuring out the issue.

```
select *, volume/ case when National_Avg=0 then 1 else National_Avg end as FPD_Renewals 

from ( 

select convert(decimal(10,0), COUNT(srf_borrower)*1.8) as Volume, year(datecompleted) as cal_year, month(datecompleted) as cal_month
from database1.dbo.datafile
where month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
      and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
group by month(datecompleted), year(datecompleted))a

join(select cal_date, National_Avg
from database1.dbo.calendar
where cal_date = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
    AND cal_date  = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp)))b

    on a.cal_year = b.cal_date and a.cal_month = b.cal_date
```

I want the query to display the results for the previous month, So when the year and month from table 1 matches the year from table 2. The datatype from table 1 is 'datetime' and the datatype from table 2 is 'datetime' as well. Within my calendar table I have several columns, two alternatives I have are the 'year' and 'month' column but these datatypes are not 'datetime' and sql gives me a conversion error.

Some sample data from table 2:

```
Table 1
ID cal_month cal_year     cal_date  fy_date    Tor Mtl National_avg
1   January   2018      2018-01-01 2018-01-01  22  22       22
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it ? 
Thank you everyone

Comment: Looks like the problem is date handling logic to me, cal_date is what type? its being compared to a year number and a month number as a numeric.

Comment: cal_date = datetime
datecompleted = datetime

Comment: When you are missing query results, then you have a condition that isn't matching or resuting as true in either an `INNER JOIN`, a `WHERE`, a `HAVING` or a `CROSS APPLY`. Check if your subqueries are returing data on their own, then check if the joining column values match on both sides of the join.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci My sub queries do individually return results, I am new to joins/ temp tables hence my struggle. Logic is - take current month and -1 to get previous month for both sub queries, then given the month & year  from table 2 matches table 1, display x

Comment: @Pat - `a.cal_year = b.cal_date and a.cal_month = b.cal_date` in that part of the query, cal_date is being compared to a year value, and also compared to a month value. Date logic does not work like that, and I suspect cal_date is an actual date. The use of dates and date logic in this statement is suspect, in some ways you would be better adding in some example data, example output and the query you have so far, so that people can advise on the corrections.

Comment: @Andrew Even when I remove the second half after the 'and' and leave it as a.cal_year = b.cal_date the results are blank 

Table 1 should return for example 300 for February
Table 2 should return 19.5 days

The temptable is supposed to take 300 / 19.5 and display the result

Comment: if cal_year is a year, such as 2018, so that's an integer, and cal_date is an actual date, then the comparison of the two will not work, if you mean a.cal_year = year(b.cal_date) then you have to explicitly write that. Your use of dates / year function / month functions is unusual and appears to be misunderstanding the nature of dates in the database / language.

Comment: You expect a year to match a date?

Comment: I don't understand, the datatypes are the same for datecompleted and cal_date (both are 'datetime') . I just want subquery 1 to get my previous months result of X and subquery 2 to identify the # of working days for previous month then just divide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second subquery just needs to pull out month and year so you can compare apples to apples.

```
SELECT
  *,
  volume / CASE
    WHEN National_Avg = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE National_Avg
  END AS FPD_Renewals

FROM (SELECT
  CONVERT(decimal(10, 0), COUNT(srf_borrower) * 1.8) AS Volume,
  YEAR(datecompleted) AS cal_year,
  MONTH(datecompleted) AS cal_month
FROM database1.dbo.datafile
WHERE MONTH(datecompleted) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, current_timestamp))
AND YEAR(datecompleted) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, current_timestamp))
GROUP BY MONTH(datecompleted),
         YEAR(datecompleted)) a

JOIN (SELECT
  cal_date,
  National_Avg,
  YEAR(cal_date) AS cal_year,
  MONTH(cal_date) AS cal_month
FROM database1.dbo.calendar
WHERE MONTH(cal_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, current_timestamp))
AND YEAR(cal_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, current_timestamp))) b

  ON a.cal_year = b.cal_year
  AND a.cal_month = b.cal_month
```

Comment: this worked... Thank you Nik.. learned from my struggles.. cheers :D

Comment: If I wanted to take the result of my query and divide it by x, how would I approach that?

Comment: Not quite sure what 'x' is in this context, but you can either wrap this as a sub-query (like you're already doing) or store the results in a temporary table. Depending what 'x' is, you may be able to use AVG or COUNT to get the value to divide by.